# Automatically start app on boot from code

Tags: android

I have configured my app to automatically start on boot and it's working but only the first time :/

The manifest

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PRIVILEGED_PHONE_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SHUTDOWN"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PREVENT_POWER_KEY" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />

  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REBOOT" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DEVICE_POWER" />

 <receiver android:name=".autostart" android:enabled="true" android:exported="true">
      <intent-filter>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON"/>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.REBOOT"/>
        <!--For HTC devices-->
        <action android:name="com.htc.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON"/>
      </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

The autostart

```
public class autostart extends BroadcastReceiver {
  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
      Intent i = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
      i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
      context.startActivity(i);
      Log.d("AutoStart", "AutoStart");
  }
}
```

I restart and shutdown the app with this code :

```
  public static void Reboot(CaniGPSApplication caniGPSApplication) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "/system/bin/svc", "power", "reboot" });
    proc.waitFor();
  }


  public static void Shutdown(CaniGPSApplication caniGPSApplication) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "/system/bin/svc", "power", "shutdown" });
    proc.waitFor();
  }
```

I have no idea why my apps doesn't start the second time. I am working on a GPS device (no screen ...) and my app is in system/priv-app .

Hope someone will have an idea :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution.

First I remove autostart block which is not more used

```
<receiver android:name=".autostart"
```

And I have added the HOME category in my main activity

```
<activity
      android:name=".MainActivity"
      android:exported="true">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

From the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#CATEGORY_HOME)

> This is the home activity, that is the first activity that is
> displayed when the device boots.

Perfect for my case : a simple GPS device, but I think a bad idea on a phone :)